# jquery bind keyup to body in firefox

Tags: jquery, bind, keypress, onkeyup

i m binding keyup function in jquery to body which works in every browser
except firefox

the code: -

```
 $('body').bind('keyup', function(e) {
    //alert ( e.which );
    alert('testing');

});
```

how do i do it for firefox. it does not responds at all

thanks

Answer (score 26, accepted):

bind the event to the `document` instead:

```
$(document).bind('keyup', function(e) {
    alert('testing');
});
```

You can make almost any node receive keyboard events. In "modern" browsers, you can setup a `tabIndex`. After that the event is focusable.

```
$(document.body).attr('tabIndex', 1).bind('keyup', function(e) {
    alert('testing');
});
```

Comment: Thanx it save's my time also :)

Comment: Good God Andy, I can't thank you enough for this answer, I was having an awful time trying to understand why is it not working with `$("body").bind(...)`!